# How are bonus feats affected by reincarnate?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, reincarnation

How are bonus feats affected by reincarnate exactly?

> A reincarnated creature recalls the majority of its former life and form. It retains any class abilities, feats, or skill ranks it formerly possessed.
>
> The reincarnated creature gains all abilities associated with its new form, including forms of movement and speeds, natural armor, natural attacks, extraordinary abilities, and the like, but it doesn’t automatically speak the language of the new form.

Strongheart Halflings and Humans both get a bonus feat at first level. If one were to reincarnate into the other, would they gain an extra feat?

If 6th level fighter would be reincarnated how his feats would be affected? Would he preserve feats for 1st, 3rd and 6th level as well as fighter feats for 1st, 2nd, 4th and 6th level? If yes then what would happen when he advances to fighter's 6th level once again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly the way I would run it is that if a character’s race contributed a bonus feat, and they were *reincarnated*, they would lose a feat. I would personally not be a stickler on *which one*, however, since losing one’s first feat might mean losing the use of *all* of your feats, if they all depended on that first one. That’s no good. But I also wouldn’t insist it be the latest one, since that one may be better than what one could have gotten at 1st. I would leave that up to the character’s player.

I would also require them to re-take that same feat if they were *reincarnated* into another race with a bonus feat. So the formerly-human strongheart halfling would see no change in feats. I don’t think *reincarnate* should be a way to swap feats. However, in the case of two separate *reincarnates*, with some time in between (say, at least one level-up), I would probably allow a different feat (especially if they had regained that feat some other way in the interim).

But none of this is explicitly stated in the rules. The rules ignore this possibility entirely, and it’s rather unclear what should happen.

Answer (score 5):

A Strongheart Halfling reincarnated into a human (or vice versa) would not get an extra feat. From [the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/races.htm#humans):

> 1 extra feat at 1st level.

Since the character wouldn't be gaining their first level, they wouldn't get the bonus feat.

---

> If 6th level fighter would be reincarnated how his feats would be affected.

You refer to the loss of 1 level experienced when reincarnating.

Also from [the SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#levelLoss):

> the character loses any ability score gain, skill ranks, and any feat associated with the level

So:

> Would he preserve feats for 1st, 3rd and 6th level as well as fighter feats for 1st, 2nd, 4th and 6th level?

The wording is a little fuzzy here. It first says that feats et al are retained and *then* says that a level is lost.

I would apply these in order. First everything is retained (i.e. you don't start from scratch), then the level loss is applied.

Therefore the two feats gained at level 6 would both be lost.

> If yes then what would happen when he advances to fighter's 6th level once again?

The character would level up as normal and select a new feat for level 6 and a new fighter bonus feat (assuming they leveled up as a fighter).

Comment: Do you mean to say that someone who wasn’t human that becomes human through *reincarnate* loses whatever racial features they had, but **doesn’t** gain the primary human feature, the bonus feat? Also, what happens if the character was 2nd level before *reincarnate*, and thus **is** 1st level? Would you say that the human→strongheart would gain an extra feat in that situation?

Comment: I think Quentin is right, though it does suck, but that's kinda the danger of the *reincarnate* spell. I mean, it sucks if you get half-orc and then can't cast your high level wizard spells too.